# How to handle Microsoft Word character encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-word

I have a simple text area on a page. When you click submit, it grabs the value of the text area and stores it into the database.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="theField" placeholder="Enter Data">
```

When a user types the following into the field it stores it fine: `"this is a test" item's`

However, if they type that into microsoft word and then paste it into the field, the outcome is : `â€œThis is a testâ€ for itemâ€™s`

All I am doing is getting the value like so: `var nominee = $('#theField').val()`

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but something like it is probably all you can do:

```
var ldquo = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(226, 8364, 339), "g"),
    rsquo = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(226, 8364, 8482), "g"),
    rdquo = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(226, 8364), "g");

var clean = $("#theField").val()
    .replace(ldquo, '"')
    .replace(rsquo, "'")
    .replace(rdquo, '"');
```

You need to additionally figure out what the left single "smart" quote looks like. Of course the patterns above may not be correct; the whole thing is a result of a collision between two character encodings.